# If condition inside mysql query

Tags: mysql, if-statement

I need to give condition inside mysql query ,

```
    select IF(r.name=NULL,'customer',r.name) as previlage 
 from users u LEFT JOIN role r on r.rid = u.uid ORDER BY u.created DESC\G
```

i need to check `if the r.name field is null then it should be displayed as 
customer` ,but now `if r.name is NULL then its displayed as null itself` . How  can i achieve this .Thank you .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not compare `NULL` with `=` , you need to use `is null`

```
r.name is null
```

instead of

```
r.name=NULL
```

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/working-with-null.html